# Is it possible to create a Windows Form in a C# Class Library?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, dll

I've been building DLL class libraries in C#, used as add-ons to an application which provides a Custom API.  Up until now they've included mostly interfacing with databases, calculations, disk operations and so forth.  I'm curious to know if I can build and display a Windows Form, displaying text boxes, buttons and so forth, inside a DLL Class Library?

I tried:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

But that namespace is not recognized.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: I just right clicked on class library > Add > New Item > Window Form with no problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: In addidtion to the uses clauses also compare the references to those of a forms project!

Answer (score 12):

What I find works best for me is to create a new Windows Forms project, and then go to the project properties and change it to a class library. This way, you can right click on folders in the solution explorer and all the WinForms items appear just as if it were still a WinForms project, but it's a class library. This also works with WPF applications.

Comment: and delete Program.cs from the classlib's project, JIC

Comment: This answer is brilliant. Just brilliant. It will save a lot of people time and money. Take a bow, sir.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2019, I notice that there is now a `Windows Forms Class Library` template available which should save a bit of time.

Answer (score 10):

You can definitely use Windows Forms inside your class library. There are few scenarios:

1. You are adding a form to the library using FormDesigner. You can right click on project name, click on Add and then in Windows form. It should add required References for your form
2. You are copying a form from other project. In this case the Visual Studio will not be able to identify the form and will show it as simple C# source file. In this case right click on References under the project in Visual Studio. Click on Add References and select `Framework` from left pane. Select `System.Windows.Form` and `System.Drawing` and click Ok. This should make the form understandable to Visual Studio and you can design it edit it using Form Designer.
3. If you are creating form using code, add the references to required assemblies as mentioned in the step 2. You should be able to use `System.Windows.Form` in your project with `using System.Windows.Form;` statement.

Answer (score 7):

You can manually edit the project file to include windows forms:

Right click the project file --> "Edit Project File" and then under the `<PropertyGroup>` tag, add `"<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>"`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>    
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. You need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` in the class library project (right-click on project -> Add -> Reference)

Answer (score 1):

It's 2021-7-29 and I'm using VS2019 and net5.

When creating a new project, there is a template named "Windows Form Class Library", with App.WindowsForm in it's dependencies as default.

God and Microsofters heard our pray.

Answer (score -1):

if the New form is already in a Windows project that has to stay windows
application..

try these Steps not sure if this is what you want... hope it helps.

1. Create new Dll Project
2. Copy Form.cs, FormDesigner.cs and form.resx
   into the new dll project Folder
3. Add Existing

Comment: This is 'a' solution but it is not convenient. Instead, I would create a Windows Forms Application project and change the output type to class library. That would help with adding required references and using them.