# Create Windows Form as Class Library

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-assembly

I am trying to make a `windows form` to be reused across several projects. So I thought this would be a class library. What I want to do is call `WindowsForm.Show()` as a static call. I've tried to create a class library but I cannot reach the resources for an icon. I then created a `WinForms` project, but it wants a 'New' in the program.cs. I do not want to call

```
WindowsForm form = new WindowsForm() 
form.show()
```

How do i create a reusable static form? I hope i'm being clear.

Comment: It's doable. Dll containing `Form`/`UserControl`/whatever. Is you real problem *"can't reach the resources for an icon"*? Expose it as another `static` property to set later. Or pass as a parameter to static method which will create instance and show form.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687959/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-form-in-a-c-sharp-class-library

Comment: That's all sort of doable, a class factory is an obvious alternative, but ignoring the fact that a form is not actually "reusable" is going to byte pretty bad sooner or later.  Once it is closed it is *not* usable anymore and trying to use it anyway generates ObjectDisposedException.  That can be hacked around but form objects are pretty expensive.  You are essentially creating a memory leak.  Just don't.

Comment: What's wrong with `(new WindowsForm()).Show()` anyway?

Answer (score 2):

To add a factory method you can do:

```
public static MyForm ShowNew()
{
    MyForm form = new MyForm();
    return form;
}
```

About resources, it depends on what you're using the icon for. If the icon is always the same and it always will be, then add it to your library Properties/Resources (if you don't see it, go on your library project properties, on the tab *Resources*, and click add). Otherwise, add a parameter to your factory method (and to the form constructor as well) and pass it when you call the form:

```
public static MyForm ShowNew(Icon ico)
{
    MyForm form = new MyForm(ico);
    return form;
}
```

When instantiating

```
MyForm.ShowNew(Properties.Resources.my_icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be implementing your form as usual, wrapping it in a Singleton-like class :

```
public static class WindowsFormSingleton {

    // A static instance of your form
    private static WindowsForm _form;

    // A singleton property to interact with the form.
    public static WindowsForm Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(_form == null) {
                this._form = new WindowsForm();
            }
            else if(_form.IsDisposed) {
                this._form = new WindowsForm();
            }

            return this._form;
        }
    }
}
```

... and using the singleton instance like the following :

```
WindowsFormSingleton.Instance.Show();
```

---

*Note: As [taffer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5114784/taffer) stated in the comments, [using a Factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33805514/824495) to always create a new instance would be a better approach to this.*

Comment: This is a bad idea. Once the form is closed, it will be unusable. It would be better if a static factory method always created a new instance.

Comment: Hmm. If the only problem is the disposal, would checking `IsDisposed` property when creating a new instance save us?

Comment: Or, I would just publish a static `Show` method, which could always create or re-use a form. Similarly to `MessageBox`.